# Access getters inside the Vue Class Component decorator

Tags: typescript, vue.js, eslint

After upgrading ESLint and other packages in my project I started getting the following error in some of my components:

`'InsertClassNameHere' was used before it was defined`

[image: ESLint Error]

The problem is that I need to access the getters from inside the class below the @Component decorator. This only worked if I explicitly set the type on the Component decorator like so:

`@Component<InsertClassNameHere>`

After the upgrade it no longer works because of the ESLint error.

When I remove the class name reference from the @Component decorator, the getters are no longer accessible:

[image: ESLint Error 2]

Do you know how I can either reference the class name below the decorator or access the getters of the component without referencing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably due the ESLint rule [`no-use-before-define`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-use-before-define). Your code seems to be relying on accessing [hoisted](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_hoisting.asp) identifiers before they are defined. Therefore it might be best to disable that rule entirely for your SFCs.